# What's the format of this password value?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, passwords, hashcode, password-encryption

What is the format/hash type that is used, to generate a value for a password, like this:

**1000:Z7yApDhypjU88p8cTU3SLRGqW6cZXtbv:oThRlVGlTNMggciquvhXn6jjvnaoRfFM**

I only know that runs behing an asp.net webapi app on Azure.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just wondering if by any chance, someone would recognize this algorithm/format...that's it. And give me the name of that format so I could properly document it. Unfortunatelly I was provided only with a sample xml file and nothing more. All the fields there are self-explanatory....but this hash format I never saw it in my life...that's why I asked

Answer (score 1):

(If this is a real hash, please consider obfuscating/"generic-alizing" them in the future)

Do you have more than one sample, such that you can tell if the format and length:

`([integer (user id? rounds?)]:[32 bytes]:[32 bytes])`

... is exact and consistent?

If so, it doesn't directly match (including length) any of the example hashes on the hashcat wiki:

https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes

I tentatively conclude that it's either a custom format, or indirectly related somehow to [the Azure AD password hash sync format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnectsync-implement-password-hash-synchronization):

> - The password hash synchronization agent expands the 16-byte binary password hash to 64 bytes by first converting the hash to a 32-byte
>     hexadecimal string, then converting this string back into binary with
>     UTF-16 encoding.
> - The password hash synchronization agent adds a salt, consisting of a 10-byte length salt, to the 64-byte binary to further protect the
>     original hash.
> - The password hash synchronization agent then combines the MD4 hash plus salt, and inputs it into the PBKDF2 function. 1000 iterations of
>     the HMAC-SHA256 keyed hashing algorithm is used.
> - The password hash synchronization agent takes the resulting 32-byte hash, concatenates both the salt and the number of SHA256 iterations
>     to it (for use by Azure AD), then transmits the string from Azure AD
>     Connect to Azure AD over SSL.

So the '1000' at the beginning might be the number of rounds. It's a wild guess, though.

Comment: Thanks very much for your input. The samples I was provided with have the same length and format...that's consisten. Definitively googling it and using the example hashes table you mentioned didn't shed much light... basically as I udnertstand it...it can be anything